Scheduling Delta Waves Skill to play nightly
I had the Green Noises skill set to play at 2100 every night but now I want to replace that with Delta Waves. I can't find how to enable that particular skill to play every night like I could witg the Green Noises skill. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
I tried going into the Delta Waves skill but that would only start it immediately and not allow me to schedule a specific time to start. I looked for the Timers API as Alexa recommended but found nothing helpful there. How can I schedule the Delta Waves skill like I did the Green Noise skill?
